# onomatopoeia: fire going out?

Tags: translation

Apparently in Sichuanese a similar term to the English “oops” or “drat” or what have you comes from the sound of a fire going out.

It is written 哦呵 (pronounced: o-ho) or 哦呵儿 (pronounced: o-her).

Is there a translation for this?

What’s the onomatopoeia for a fire going out in English?

Comment: maybe the 'hiss' of water, or 'puff' of smoke as it goes out.

Comment: Or combine them to make the singular sound ‘piss’

Comment: funnily enough there's an expression - 'don't piss on my fire' meaning don't put me out

Comment: There's *Pfft*: Used to signify a sudden ending or disappearance.

Comment: What kind of fire? How big a fire? The flame on a matchstick? A fire in a fireplace? A fire in a forest? Is the combustible substance wet or dry, old or new? Paper, oil, wood, cloth...? There are lots of fires and they don't all go out the same way.

Comment: Sometimes flames [***pop***](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=OCuWWd2sFcHejwTk_bn4CA&q=%E2%80%9Cflame+popped+and+went+out%E2%80%9D&oq=%E2%80%9Cflame+popped+and+went+out%E2%80%9D) and go out.

Answer (score 2):

*Fizzle* is what jumps to mind, as in "As the fire *fizzled*, we spoke even more quietly" or in a more figurative sense:

"Last month, two tropical storms popped up, with Tropical Storm Bret becoming the earliest to form east of the Antilles before *fizzling* offshore.
—
Jenny Staletovich, miamiherald, "Weekend tropical cyclone likely near Windward Islands", 3 July 2017

And it didn't occur to me that "fizzle" could be an example of onomatopoeia until I thought about it a bit. "Fizzle" could easily be a sound made as a fire goes out, especially if it is doused with water.